# Why this code works? These quotes don't make sense to me.

Tags: c#, cmd, command

If i remove the second quote in first line it doesn't work.

```
  string command = "/C \"rmdir /q /s \\\\"+ hostname + "\\c$\\Users\\" + user;
            var psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
            {
                Arguments = command,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            using (var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi))
            {
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
```

Comment: Well, don't remove it then

Comment: @MickyD , Please look at answer of "TheClassic" for this Post and see if your comment fits anywhere

Comment: @Saurabh If you are too silly enough to spot a friendly jibe at an obviously badly-written post (at the time of writing, a post of 3 down-votes) then you should take a read of [ask].

Comment: @MickyD Dear , Thank You so Much , I read That already Many times, And it does not say anywhere to go blindly with rules .

Answer (score 3):

Placing a slash before a character indicates that the following character should be interpreted literately and not as a compiler symbol. So

```
\\
```

becomes \ and \" becomes ". The slash string is putting a quote in the string. The command string is effectively set to (this is what print(command) would look like:

```
/C "rmdir /q /s \\hostname\c$\Users\user
```

assuming hostname="hostname" and user="user"

The strange thing about this code is that there isn't a second closing quote in the string.

I would expect it should be more like:

```
string command = "/C \"rmdir /q /s \\\\"+ hostname + "\\c$\\Users\\\"" + user;
```

which will add a closing quote. If you want to remove the quote before rmdir, you'll want to remove the slash too.

See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available/

Comment: Removing the quote and the slash works. That's more readable, thanks!
But i still can't understand why the first way worked.

Comment: @JhonSimpson Because its not a quote in the code, its a quote in the string... look at what would happen if you print the string in the block in my answer